# SharePoint 2013 Online SharePoint Server Publishing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a subsite in SharePoint 2013 online that i have modifiyed with changes. I use publishing images, and have a newslider on first page i have created. The pictures uses publishing images.

Now i want to save my site as a template but its working becouse the
SharePoint Server-publishing feature is active, now the question..

If i turn the feature off, will my site/template break?

Answer (score 1):

The site won't break, but you will lose the publishing feature functionality.

Read more in [Publishing features overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff628963%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I fixed it by myself, from sharepoint designer , site options in sharepoint designer, SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled = True,